# Add hyperlinks in Leaflet layercontrol

Tags: leaflet, hyperlink, layer-control

Id like to add hyperlinks to the layers in my layer control.
[Leaflet site](http://faculty.salisbury.edu/~sehamilton/LV_Leaflet/LV_leaflet.html)

So when you open the layer control.

[image: Layer control]

Id like to be able to add a hyperlink to Basin, shoreline etc. This is my coded.

```
    //create basemaps variable to call within the control
        var baseMaps = {
            "Open Street Map": osm,
            "ESRI Imagery": Esri_WorldImagery,
            "OpenTopoMap": OpenTopoMap,
            "Bing Imagery": bingLayer
        };

        //create overlays variable to call within the control. Calls layer groups
        var overLays = {
            "Basin": aShp,
            "Rivers":bShp,
            "Sub-basins":cShp,
            "Shoreline":dShp,
            "Country Boundaries":eShp,
            "Partner Research Institutions":fShp,
            "Bathymetry":both
        };

        //add control to map
        L.control.layers(baseMaps, overLays).addTo(map);
        bathyImage.addTo(map);
        bathyImage2.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

It was just a single double quote issue. Had them the wrong way around.

```
"<a target='_blank' href='http://dx.doi.org/10.7910/DVN/Z5RMYD'>Basin</a>": aShp,
            "<a target='_blank' href='http://dx.doi.org/10.7910/DVN/ITMMCB'>Rivers</a>":bShp,
            "<a target='_blank' href='http://dx.doi.org/10.7910/DVN/LCW9VA'>Sub-basins</a>":cShp,
            "<a target='_blank' href='http://dx.doi.org/10.7910/DVN/PWFW26'>Shoreline</a>":dShp,
            "Country Boundaries":eShp,
            "Partner Research Institutions":fShp,
            "<a target='_blank' href='http://dx.doi.org/10.7910/DVN/SOEKNR'>Bathymetry</a>":both
```